# Suitable font size for road network for A0 -A1 print size QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography

I need to print big paper maps, Im using QGIS to design my maps.
But I would like to get advice on suitable front size for road names. With the map as big as A0 I can basically fit all text labels for every road.
Is the point size the same as font size in QGIS for labels? So that a font size 1 is 9 pixels big?

Comment: I would assume that point size is the same as font size, but I'm not sure in QGIS's case. As a general cartographic rule of thumb, don't go smaller than size 6 font.

Comment: Thanks, I printed small sections of the map with different labels and I think font 6 was a pretty good size to keep the text readable without being to outstanding.